# Does it make sense to say "someone is the reason and purpose for me of doing something?"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I'd like to put this in acknowledgements of my dissertation, expressing that someone is very important to me:

> X is the reason and purpose for me of writing this dissertation.

But is that a meaningful and grammatically correct sentence? If not, how should I rephrase it?

Comment: "X is my reason and purpose in writing this dissertation" would be shorter. Fussier would be "X is my reason *for* and purpose in writing this dissertation."

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, @Robusto. Can I say "X is the reason and purpose for me in writing this dissertation?" Because I already said "X is my blablabla" in the previous sentence and would like to avoid repetition.

Comment: The possessive ("*my* purpose in writing")  is clearer than the prepositional ("purpose *for me* in writing") and more idiomatic.

Comment: @YingXiong: In that case use a pronoun instead of X. "He [or she] is my reason . . ."

Comment: I am uncomfortable with saying "Joe Blow is my purpose for writing"; it just does not sound right. Usually, a purpose is linked to a pre-determined outcome, as in "My purpose was to help Joe Blow." Now if you were to say "Joe Blow is my reason for writing," the sound of the sentence is much better, and in essence you are paying Joe Blow a compliment. In other words, if it weren't for Joe Blow, you would never have written your dissertation.

Comment: Slightly off topic, since it is a grammar question but I do suggest the more common etiquette is using something like "X motivated me to write this." or "X is my motivation for writing this". If it's near the beginning, prior to the main body of the work "This Y is dedicated to X, who Z."  with Z being a brief clause explaining the motivation, for example "This work is dedicated to J. Smith, who aided my studies immensely." If X happens to be a somebody you amorously admire, do keep in mind that it might be embarrassing to mention that, except maybe if the love is already known to be requited.

Comment: @rhetorician: Think more figuratively. Language is bigger than you may suppose.

Comment: @Robusto: Point taken. Had I been crafting an answer instead of just a comment, rest assured I woulda come up with 20 different ways of saying pretty much the same thing. Ideation is second nature to me. (That and five bucks will get you a coffee at Starbucks! Although, my ideation did come in handy many years ago when I was a-learnin' my university students.) Don

Comment: @Tonepoet I was thinking right along the same lines; why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @W9WBH Using "if" at the beginning of the rephrase request technically makes it qualified by what precedes it. The question is first and foremost if the proposed sentence is correct and meaningful. I lack the knowledge to make the first judgement and I think I understand the sentiment, since I have encountered "is the reason and purpose" before, even if it is less common. I also lack the citations to make it more than an anecdotal answer. If you or anybody else believes it should be an answer and are able to make a good one, please feel free to provide it. I just felt it was a worthy footnote.

Answer (score -1):

I would NOT say someone is the reason and purpose for you doing something, especially if it is a college project, which is for an academic task, etc.  Your dissertation is your OWN generated work topic, which you have studied for. You can acknowledge a supervising Professor, Don, or Tutor for their assistance, etc.